# Is constantly making new objects normal?

Tags: c#, single-responsibility-principle

ANSWER: Even though turning the classes into variables instead and then calling them would work, in this case it is likely a sign of bad design. A better design will have the side-effect that constantly making new instances of classes isn't required to begin with.

============

Lately I've been (attempting to) apply the SRP to my code, splitting up all responsibilities to separate classes. It has worked very well, maintainability and reusability of code went up tons.. yet I find myself constantly doing things like `new Table.Type("messages").Get(id);`.

Most of my classes contain only one method. Still.. it feels awkward. Guts say this is the point where I might as well turn them all into static classes.

So I figured I'd turn to my more experienced seniors, is frequently writing 'new Class().Method()' commonly done? Or is there a better way to handle it?

Example code:

```
public void AdminCommands(Channel channel, IrcUser user, string message)
{
    var command = message.Split(' ')[0];
    switch (command)
    {
        case "@info":
            GetInfo(channel, message);
            break;
        //----a couple of more commands
    }
}

private void GetInfo(Channel channel, string message)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(message, "@info (.+)");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string search = match.Groups[1].Value;
        //Get stored data on the word or sentence, and send the result to chat.
        new CommandInfo().Execute(search);  //<-------------------- over here.
        return;
    }
    Chat.SendAdminMessage("Message not found.");
}
private void EditMessage(Channel channel, string message)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(message, "@edit (.+?) (.+?) (.+?)=(.+)");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string type = match.Groups[1].Value;
        string id = match.Groups[2].Value;
        string toReplace = match.Groups[3].Value;
        string replaceWith = match.Groups[4].Value;

        //Gets message of 'type' by 'id', and store it back after editing.
        new CommandEdit().Execute(type, id, toReplace, replaceWith); //<-here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Having lots of classes that do one thing is fine, but don't make them static, because then you can't use composition.

Comment: You don't have to create a new class if you don't want too.. remember making new classes uses more memory in your program and if the class could be a utility class then there is no reason to keep re-initializing it.

Comment: I certainly can't see any reason to do what you have done. What, in your mind, are the pros and cons? For me I see no pros in doing it your way  and the obvious con of you creating lots of pointless instances of objects that you don't need.

Comment: @NWard: In this case composition is irrelevant since they are not being passed into the class in any way, just hard coded there.

Comment: There is not complete context here, but what I would typically do is have a private `ICommandInfo _commandInfo` member that gets initialized once in the constructor (or perhaps injected as an argument) and then use `_commandInfo.Execute` rather than create a new one each time. This also allows for mocking.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error You took the words right out of my mouth.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a huge list of variables with each and every Command I would eventually add, but that does seem to be more common practice than creating all kinds of needless instances over and over. Thanks for your help, y'all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell from your example code, but you seem to be creating procedural code with a pretend overcoat of object orientation.

I can't tell anything about your code from your object model. For instance, what exactly does this line do?

```
new CommandInfo().Execute(search);
```

What is a CommandInfo object? What does it represent? What on earth does an Execute() function do? I have no idea.

The whole point of objects is that they encapsulate some kind of internal state. If you are constantly newing things up then they obviously don't have any state.

A lot of your code seems to be operating on messages, so why not put methods that operate on messages on the message class?

```
Message.GetInfo();
Message.Edit();
```

etc. It's difficult to suggest a model when I can't work out what the code it doing, but can you see how much more obvious this makes the code?.

Comment: I think you are correct here, my code does behave like procedural code more than OO-type code. Does this mean that I shouldn't apply OO principles? Or just.. different ones?

Comment: I would say that you're not really applying OO principles at the moment. Doing so properly would remove all the newing but it's not something you can easily describe in a few words.

Answer (score 3):

you can of course store CommandEdit and CommandInfo as member variables and then call Execute

```
private CommandInfo mInfo = new CommandInfo();

private void GetInfo(Channel channel, string message)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(message, "@info (.+)");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string search = match.Groups[1].Value;
        //Get stored data on the word or sentence, and send the result to chat.
        mInfo.Execute(search);  //<-------------------- over here again.
        return;
    }
    Chat.SendAdminMessage("Message not found.");
}
```

Comment: I've considered turning them into member variables, but the more commands there will be, it will just be a huge list of variables. Which means that if something changes, I'll have to (needlessly, maybe?) edit  the code in two locations instead of one. It -would- mean I don't have to spend system resources in remaking the class, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you review your Object-Model and and verify the design that led to 1-1 class-method.  In case you still think your modelling is acceptable, I would not recommend the static class approach, specially if you are into unit-testing, this could make your automated testing eventually challenging.

Instead of static, consider implementing a basic singlton:

```
public class Work
{
 private static readonly Lazy<Work> _work = new Lazy<Work>(()=> new Work());

 public static Work Instance{get{return _work.Value;}} 

 public void DoWork(){}
}
```

the call to it:

```
Work.Instance.DoWork();
```

Comment: I used to have a larger class with all the methods for several commands. Then it would make sense to just make a field for the class, and call the corresponding command. In my attempt to apply the SRP, I was like.. "but what if this command changes? Or this one, or this one?", and I ended up splitting everything into classes with single methods. Maybe I am misunderstanding the principle?

Comment: What I understood is you seem to have lots of common code with slight differences in what you call the command area.  Sounds like you could clean it up using abstract classes and generics? From example if all your logic takes in a channel and message to execute a command, you could abstract the command execution part and have child classes that implement only the command execution part?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a field for your class that hold a reference to the object you are constantly creating?
Like this you avoid Garbage collection and you are not creating useless object see :

```
public class myClass{
...
private ICommandInfo commandInfo= new CommandInfo();

private void GetInfo(Channel channel, string message)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(message, "@info (.+)");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string search = match.Groups[1].Value;
        //Get stored data on the word or sentence, and send the result to chat.
        commandInfo.Execute(search);  //<-------------------- no object creation.
        return;
    }
    Chat.SendAdminMessage("Message not found.");
}
...
}
```

I will tend to go futher using an interface `ICommandInfo` that will make testing and mocking easier.

Answer (score 1):

A class providing some sort of functionality can also be considered to be a service in a very general sense. It is a good idea ([Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), [Inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)) to inject this services in consuming classes.

```
public class Consumer
{
    private ICommandService _commandInfo;

    public Consumer(ICommandService commandInfo)
    {
        _commandInfo = commandInfo;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _commandInfo.Execute();
    }
}
```

Such services can be created once on application start. Or implement the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Using injection allows you to use different implementations without the consuming classes to be aware of it. You can even inject dummy classes when making [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) (see [Mock object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)).

---

In your example it is not clear on what `Execute` is applied, since `CommandInfo` seems not to contain any data. Your comment says "... and send the result to chat". Why not use a chat object injected into the class?

```
_chat.Send(search);
```

This is more speaking than `new CommandInfo().Execute(search);` and the comment becomes obsolete. Comments explaining the code are often a hint that something is wrong with the code. Comments providing background information are okay.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't looked at it this way. I could, for example.. make a 'CommandService' once, pass it along to whichever message enters the system, and then I can call the commands from each message itself. That would even allow me to make different commands per type of message. I'll.. look into this some more. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. In order to take full advantage of it, let the services implement an interface and programm against the interface.